# Trying to troubleshoot Web API Route Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an application that had working routes for several Web API Controllers.  Suddenly, when switching between branches, the routes fail in certain branches, but work in others.

When looking at the files (I think are in play):  Web.config, WebAPIConfig.cs, Gobal.asax and the Controllers themselves, none of the files change in the working/non-working branches.

My question is:  Are there other files in play that I should be looking at and/or how can I see which files are actually changing when Visual Studio does it's GIT calls while changing branches?  When looking at source tree and compare a working branch to a non-working branch, I see no differences that should be causing the issue.

Comment: No, this application does not have a RouteConfig.cs

Comment: Sorry, as it currently stands, this question is too broad to answer. You need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to debug this.